# Pivot Pandas dataframe and make existing columns row 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I am trying to pivot a table to make one column the new column headers but also retain all existing columns as a 2nd row of columns. This specific formatting is required for input into another process. All values still need to pivot as normal to match new orientation.

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhkCX.png)
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShQDk.png)

I'm pretty far off I believe on this, don't have much experience with pivots with this additional requirement. I can complete pivots normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `column 2` as index then use  [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column 1': [1, 2, 3],
        'Column 2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Column 3': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = df.set_index(["Column 2"]).unstack()
```

**Note** :  The output of [pd.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) is an [Pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) use to_frame to convert it to Dataframe :

```
new_df = new_df.to_frame()
```

Then , to get the desired output you need to take the transpose and swap the column level :

```
new_df.T.swaplevel(axis=1)
```